# Add text to TextArea from Button

Tags: html, button, textarea

Is there a way to set text in a `TextArea`? I have four `Buttons` and when I click on a `Button` I want the text in the `Button` to appear in the `TextArea`.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practice.css">

<script>
var elem = document.getElementById('ta1');

function displayText(e){
    elem.setText(elem.getText());
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input class="button" type="button" id="button0" value="testing1"/>
        <input class="button" type="button" id="button1" value="testing2" />
        <input class="button" type="button" id="button2" value="testing3"/>
        <input class="button" type="button" id="button3" value="testing4"/>

    </div>


    <textarea id = "ta1" disabled rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought of creating a method `displayText(e)` that collects the `Button` text and sets it in the `TextArea`. But I am not sure how to access the `Button` text. And once I get the text, how do I save it in the `TextArea`? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .value property to display preset text into a text area.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <textarea id="demo" cols="10" rows="20">
 </textarea>

 <script>

 var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
 for(var i = 0; i < cars.length;i++){
      document.getElementById("demo").value += " " + cars[i];
 }
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

So do you mean like this?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', start, false);
        function start(){
            document.getElementById("button0").addEventListener("click", function(){addText(this);} );
            document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){addText(this);} );
            document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){addText(this);} );
            document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){addText(this);} );

            function addText(elem) {

                document.getElementById("ta1").innerHTML += elem.value;

            }
        };


    </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <textarea id = "ta1" disabled rows="3" cols="50">
 </textarea>

        <br>
        <input class="button" type="button" id="button0" value="testing1"/>
        <input class="button" type="button" id="button1" value="testing2" />
        <input class="button" type="button" id="button2" value="testing3"/>
        <input class="button" type="button" id="button3" value="testing4"/>



</body>
</html><html>
```

Comment: yes this helps a lot! but do you know why I can't put all the document.ElementById's in the <head> section? The code does not work. However I am able to but the addText function in the <head>

Comment: thanks but would you be able to explain why before it would not work in the head tag? Just for the sake of understanding the difference between declaring something in the head tag vs. body tag

Comment: It was not working because the html content has not been loaded yet. The listeners were not working because the buttons don't exist yet. By adding `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',` `start, false);` It listens for the html too load and then runs the function `start()`

Answer (score 0):

for each button, give an onclick to a separate function and have each function look something like this:

```
function button1 () {
    var node = document.createTextNode(x); /*var x, or whatever you want the variable
    to be called will be the text  you want it to display. You will have to define this in
    an earlier variable already defined*/
    var container = document.getElementById("ta1");
    container.appendChild(node); //Appends text node to inside the TA
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it by adding "onclick" to the input statement as follows:

```
// add **onclick="function()"** to the button
<div>
<input class="button" type="button" id="button0" value="testing1" onclick="addText1"/>
<input class="button" type="button" id="button1" value="testing2" onclick="addText2"/>
<input class="button" type="button" id="button2" value="testing3" onclick="addText3"/>
<input class="button" type="button" id="button3" value="testing4" onclick="addText4"/>
</div>

// use stylesheet for positioning, etc.
<div id="text1"></div>
<div id="text2"></div>
<div id="text3"></div>
<div id="text4"></div>

//now when you click the button, it will call the respective function in the script

<script>
var text1 = "Enter text 1";
var text2 = "Enter text 2";
var text3 = "Enter text 3";
var text4 = "Enter text 4";
function addText1(){document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML += text1;}
function addText2(){document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML += text2;}
function addText3(){document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML += text3;}
function addText4(){document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML += text4;}
</script>
```